# Wrong hd mount after rhel kernel upgrade

Tags: kernel, rhel

Lately I have upgrade my RHEL 9.1 to version 9.2.
After restarting, the system started with kernel 9.2 but want into recovery mode.
When trying to start again but in the grub menu choosing kernel 9.1, it load OK.
In this mode, I want into boot directory in:
/boot/loader/entries/
There I checked the entry for the last kernel which was stuck and the previous version which  was ok.
I found out that in the last kernel, The root was mount to a very old HD which was once exist but does not exist any more. Of course that in the good entry, it is mount to a good HD.

Old and good boot entry:

```
options root=/dev/mapper/vg0-lv0 ro crashkernel=1G-4G:192M,4G-64G:256M,64G-:512M resume=/dev/mapper/vg0-swap rd.lvm.lv=vg0/lv0 rd.lvm.lv=vg0/swap rhgb quiet  $tuned_params
```

New and not good entry:

```
options root=/dev/mapper/temphd-oldhd-date ro crashkernel=1G-4G:192M,4G-64G:256M,64G-:512M resume=/dev/mapper/temphd-oldhd-date-swap rd.lvm.lv=temphd-oldhd/data rd.lvm.lv=vg0/swap rhgb quiet  $tuned_params
```

Now, if I copy the line from the old kernel entry to the new kernel entry, Every thing is ok and it load with the new kernel.

From where did the old HD name come from? For some reason when the kernel got updated it took  an old HD mout and I can't understand from where it took it, where does is it save?

I was expecting the new kernel to load with the some HD that the previous kernel was.